# On Newman/Zagier's proof of PNT

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I have just got this paper: http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.2307/2975232/fulltext.pdf and I have a serious doubt:

When proving that soft Tauberian theorem he explicitly uses analyticity of $g(s)$ in a small region on the left of  the semiplane $Re(s)>0$.

On the other hand, the function $ \Phi (s) $ has an analytic extension to the semiplane $Re(s) \geq 1$, but for the Tauberian Theorem to be of any use here, we would want the function $\Phi(s)$ to have a holomorphic extension to a certain open set containing the semiplane $Re \geq 1$; am I not right?

Therefore, I would say that we need to prove that there exist an $\epsilon >0$ such that $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros on $Re(s) \geq 1-\epsilon$...   :S

I don't believe Zagier can be wrong, so I guess either I am missing basic stuff or there is way to apply the theorem as it is.

Whatever it is, I will appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Well I don't think there is a requirement that there be a zero free region for all $\operatorname{Re}(s) > 1 - \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.  That is not even presently known, is it?  It just needs to be zero free within the semicircle.  So it really is enough just to know $\zeta$ is zero-free on the line.

Comment: It is not known, indeed, and that's what's bothering me. I don't see how checking that $\zeta$ is zero-free on the line suffices. We ought to be sure that given $R$, we can find a $\delta=\delta(R)$ such that $\zeta$ is zero-free in $[1-\delta,1] \times [-R,R]$, and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: We know that because we know there is some open set containing $\operatorname{Re}(z) \geq 0$ for which $\Phi(z)$ is holomorphic.  Because the set is _open_, we know small semicircles or rectangles are holomorphic, as long as $\delta$ is allowed to vary with $R$.  Think about this - it is really an important question you are asking.

Comment: There actually is a little subtlety here - we have to know that within any semicircle or rectangle, that there are only _finitely_ many zeros of $\zeta$.

Comment: ...and that comes from the analytic continuation of $\zeta(s) - 1/(s-1)$ to $\operatorname{Re}(s) > 0$.

Comment: I am so sorry for my thickness, but I do not see how the analytic continuation of $\zeta$ implies that it has a finite number of zeros in such regions, though I certanly understand that that fact would settle the questions.   Thanks for your answers

Comment: Zeros of holomorphic functions can not be too close together.  Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in an open region $U$, and that the zeros $\{z_n\}$ of $f$ had an accumulation point _in_ $U$ (not the boundary).  Then $f$ must be identically zero.  In particular, if $V$ is a compact subset of $U$, and $f$ has infinitely many zeros in $V$, then there must be some accumulation point of zeros in $V$, and $f$ must be identically zero.  Holomorphicity is very powerful, and is one of the few tools we really have for getting information about the zeros of the zeta function.

Comment: Now is perfectly clear. Such a nice idea! thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Part (IV) it is proven that $\zeta(s) \neq 0$ for $\operatorname{Re}(s) = 1$.  Therefore $\Phi(z)$ is holomorphic on the closed half-plane $\operatorname{Re}(z) \geq 0$.  Therefore we can analytically continue $\Phi(z)$ to *some* open set containing $\operatorname{Re}(z) \geq 0$, but as you say, we certainly do *not* know that $\Phi(z)$ can be analytically continued to $\operatorname{Re}(z) \geq -\delta$, no matter how small we make $\delta$.

However, in the proof on the "Analytic Theorem," all that is asked for is that $\Phi(z)$ is holomorphic in the region $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \;|\; |z| \leq R, \operatorname{Re}(z) \geq -\delta  \}$, where, critically, $\delta$ is **allowed to depend** on $R$.  This is certainly possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I apologize for being tiresome, but I still need some further explanation. If given $R$ we can fix $\delta$ such that $\Phi$ is holomorphic in such a region, it is because $\zeta$ is zero-free in that region. How would we prove this fact?

Comment: In order to state clearer my doubts: I certanly undestand that if $\Phi$ has an analytic extension to a certain open subset containing $Re(s) \geq 1$ we are done. What I do not understand is how can we conclude that -instead of merely the fact that $\Phi$ has an analytic extension to $Re(s) \geq 1$

Comment: Please see my last comment above.  If you have any more questions, let me know!